# CpanelInc -xmlapi-php "No host defined" Error

Tags: php, cpanel-xmlapi

Recently I am trying to create an database and its user with help of [this class](https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php). And I tried the following code.

```
include_once("xmlapi.php"); // this can be downlaoded from https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php/blob/master/xmlapi.php

$ip = getenv('REMOTE_HOST');
$root_pass = getenv('REMOTE_PASSWORD');
$xmlapi = new xmlapi($ip);
$xmlapi->password_auth("root",$root_pass);
$xmlapi->set_debug(1);
$acct = array( username => "someuser", password => "pass123", domain => "exampledoamin.com");  // here i used my domain name. 
print $xmlapi->createacct($acct);
```

but its return the following error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'No host defined' in
```

And its showing error when i require the master file. What's wrong in my code. I couldn't find the bug. Am I missed anything.

**Edit:**

Var_dump($ip);

`bool(false)`;

Comment: What does `var_dump($ip);` give you? (Note it's probably null, which will be causing that error).

Comment: i edited my question it return false. any solution for this situation

Comment: Set the `REMOTE_HOST` environment variable, or define the `XMLAPI_HOST` constant (according to the code).

Comment: please give me an example.I am newbie to work on this area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I solved the problem by rewriting the code. Here is it.

```
include_once("xmlapi.php"); 

$ip = "hostname";

$xmlapi = new xmlapi($ip);
$xmlapi->password_auth("cpanel_user-name","Password");
$xmlapi->set_port(2083);
$xmlapi->set_debug(1);

print $xmlapi->get_host();
```

Than, its connected with the host.